# jaxb2 maven plugin, define multiple schema files in separate tags

Tags: java, xsd, maven-plugin, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm using maven jaxb2 plugin to generate Java classes from xsd files. Recently i faced problem, my schema files list geting really long, and I wrote all of them down in `shemaFiles` tag as comma separated values, and the line itself is very long and i'm afraid that in future it can affect code readability and be a bug reason. So is there any solution to write files in separate tags like:

```
<schemaFilesList>
  <schemaFile>SharedResources/xsd/Common.xsd</schemaFile>
  <schemaFile>SharedResources/xsd/Another.xsd</schemaFile>
          .... 
 </schemaFilesList>
```

Here is code I have for now:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>xjc</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <extension>true</extension>
        <schemaDirectory>target/xsd</schemaDirectory>
        <!-- I have really long list of files here, in different directories-->
        <schemaFiles>
           SharedResources/xsd/Common.xsd,SharedResources/xsd/Messaging/EmailService.xsd, .....
        </schemaFiles>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `schemaFiles` node support Ant-style file patterns, so You can use this `SharedResources/xsd/**/*.xsd`. Is this can help to you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have a lot of schemas too.  We simply leave out the <schemaFiles> element and let it read all schemas in the <schemaDirectory>.